# Convert subroutine to function

Tags: excel, vba

How to convert a subroutine to function? I need to pass an argument.

```
Sub maJolieProcedure()
    With Worksheets("employes").Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(what:="Smith")
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Row
            Worksheets("employes").Rows(firstAddress).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("rapport").Range("A1")
            MsgBox "Ok"
        Else
            MsgBox "Nok"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

works.

```
Function executerMaJolieProcedure(Texte As String) As String

    '   e.g. executerMaJolieProcedure('Smith')

    With Worksheets("employes").Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(what:=Texte)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Row
            Worksheets("employes").Rows(firstAddress).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("rapport").Range("A1")
            MsgBox "Ok"
        Else
            MsgBox "Nok"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

doesnt't work.

Additional question ... How to give focus to the "employees" sheet instead of displaying the empty cell after executing the function? :)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a function, you need a **Sub with an argument**:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim s As String
    s = "whatever"
    maJolieProcedure s
End Sub


Sub maJolieProcedure(Texte As String)
    With Worksheets("employes").Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(what:=Texte)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Row
            Worksheets("employes").Rows(firstAddress).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("rapport").Range("A1")
            MsgBox "Ok"
        Else
            MsgBox "Nok"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

*(Functions in VBA are designed to only return values, not to modify worksheet cells.)*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Works perfectly.
Thanks to you, I understood how to interact with Vba from the sheet. A big step for me. :)

Comment: @384400  It took me a long time to get use to the differences between VBA functions and C functions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want data from firstAddress row in First Row (A1) in Worksheets("rapport"). It can be done using VLOOKUP function. But since you are looking for VBA code...

Following function can be entered as array formula selecting the cells in the first row. .. (Code is changed a bit)

```
Function executerMaJolieProcedure(Texte As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("employes")
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, dataRng As Range, FirstRng As Range
    lastRow = ws.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws.Cells(2, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set dataRng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A2"), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    Set FirstRng = dataRng.Find(Texte)
    executerMaJolieProcedure = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRng.Row, 1), ws.Cells(FirstRng.Row, lastCol))

End Function
```

See below screenshort.
Array Formula (Crtl+Shift+Enter) is entered in A1:I1 . The formula finds first row for "TATAMOTORS" and returns the row values from the table.

[image]

Or Vlookup in VBA

```
Function VBAVlookup(Texte As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("employes")
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, dataRng As Range, FirstRng As Range
    lastRow = ws.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws.Cells(2, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set dataRng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A2"), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    VBAVlookup = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Texte, dataRng, ActiveCell.Column, False)

End Function
```

Or simply this if Range is fixed ..

```
Function VBAVlookup3(Texte As String)
Dim DataRng As Range
Set DataRng = Worksheets("employes").Range("A:Z")
VBAVlookup3 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Texte, DataRng, ActiveCell.Column, False)
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Here give you a simple demo of how to call a function, same method with sub.

```
Sub test()

Call test2(3)

End Sub


Function test2(c) ' suggest you to use sub to change the cells.

b = 1 + c
MsgBox b

End Function
```

to change the worksheet to employes, you can

```
worksheets("employes").active
```

**I am very very curious who give me the "-1" as not useful. It is quite clear. Just copy your original code according to my solution. It works.**

```
Sub test01()

Call executerMaJolieProcedure("Smith")

End Sub
Function executerMaJolieProcedure(Texte As String) As String

    '   e.g. executerMaJolieProcedure('Smith')

    With Worksheets("employes").Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(what:=Texte)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Row
            Worksheets("employes").Rows(firstAddress).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("rapport").Range("A1")
            MsgBox "Ok"
        Else
            MsgBox "Nok"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I am very very curious who give me the "-1" as not useful. It is quite clear. Just copy your original code according to my solution.